# Regular expressions and curly braces when rendering jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2

remediation(input) is a function that include/exclude strings rendered from the template based on a boolean (with_remediation). If set to True, the word 'set' is output when rendered. Else, 'set' is omitted.

I want to include more variables to the list in addition to 'set'. In the jinja2 template there are also index numbers represented by the string `'index #'` int template. As well, There are curly braces `' { '` and `' } '` I may want to include/exclude the outputs of these strings/characters when rendering. These are the braces between `{ ipv4_mode=static }`, for example.

Question 1. Is it possible to utilize regular expression in my `temp.render(set='set')` statement below to include any numbers/digits? Something like `re.compile(r'index\s\d')='re.compile(r'index\s\d')'` How would I also handle curly braces?

Question 2. This sort of method obviously won't scale well. Every time I want to include/exclude a particular string, I need to manually add it into the `temp.render(set='set', blah='blah', etc....)` list. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

```
import jinja2

loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('/tmp')
env = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True, loader=loader)

with_remediation = False

def remediation(input):
    """Custom filter"""
    if(with_remediation):
        return input
    else:
        return ''

env.filters['remediation'] = remediation
temp = env.get_template('template.jinja2')
temp.render(set='set')
```

Template:

```
{{ set | remediation }}/settings/network_connections/ETH0/ { ipv4_mode=static } index 1
{{ set | remediation }}/settings/network_connections/ETH0/ { ipv4_address=10.0.0.10 } index 2
{{ set | remediation }}/settings/network_connections/ETH0/ { ipv4_bitmask=24 } index 3
{{ set | remediation }}/settings/network_connections/ETH0/ { ipv4_gateway=10.0.0.1 } index 4
```